# refresh a data in a datatable on the screen(jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, datatable

i have a datatable in my jsp, which fetches data from database. i've included a link in each row of the datatable which on click goes to another jsp(history.jsp) taking 2 input parameters.

### Student.jsp

```
<h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{Student.stuList}" var="stuList" >
                    <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Student Name"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{stuList.stuName}"></h:outputText>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Student Number"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{stuList.stuNum}"></h:outputText>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Student History"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:form>
                        <h:commandLink id = "historyBtn" value="Student History" action="#{stuBean.showHistory}">
                            <f:param name="sName" value="#{stuList.stuName}" />
                            <f:param name="sNumber" value="#{stuList.stuNum}" />
                        </h:commandLink></h:form>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
```

### history.jsp

```
<h:dataTable id="dt2" value="#{StuHistory.stuHistory}" var="stuHistory" >

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText style=""value="Marks in test1" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText style="" value="#{stuHistory.test1}" ></h:outputText>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Marks in test2"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{stuHistory.test2}" ></h:outputText>
                </h:column>
              </h:dataTable>
             <h:form>
           <h:commandButton id = "backBtn" value="Back to StuList" action="#{stuBean.backToStuList}">
             </h:commandButton> </h:form>
```

### StudentBean

```
public String backToStuList() {
    return "stuList";
}

public String showHistory() {
    sHistory.getStuHistory();
    return "stuHistory";
}
```

### StudentHistory.java (action class)

```
private List stuHistory = new ArrayList();
String sNum;
String sName;

public List getStuHistory() {
    getStuHistoryFromDb(sNum, sName);
    return stuHistory;
}
```

### faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>stuBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>
        com.klit.bean.StudentBean
    </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>Student</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>
        com.klit.action.Student
    </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>StuHistory</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>
        com.klit.action.StuHistory
    </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>Student.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{stuBean.showHistory}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>stuHistory</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/StudentHistory.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/StudentHistory.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{stuBean.backToStuList}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>stuList</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/Student.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

The problem I'm facing is first time when i run student.jsp it works fine but when I click on history and come back the data is appended to the existing data i.e., I have double the list size now.each time i come back it is same issue.
it is similar with my history.jsp too, there also the list is getting appended with existing data.
Any ideas to refresh the page or datatable ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a problem of scopes or list reset in your bean.

You have to make sure that either your bean and the lists are recreated each time you switch pages. This can be done by using a view scoped or request scoped bean.

Or if you need a session scoped bean you can reset the lists in your action methods.

It depends on how your lists are populated. If you post the part of your bean that fills the list, we could go further.

**UPDATE:** You have to empty your list in your `getStuHistoryFromDb` method. Put this at the beginning of the method:

```
stuHistory = new ArrayList();
```

Then your list is empty before it is filled (again). Do the same for the other list.

Comment: I've included my managed beans also where i've used session scope... do i have to make it request scoped...???

Comment: This depends on your functional requirement. You can use session scope but have to ensure, that your lists are correctly recreated each time you want to display them (added a paragraph in my answer).

Comment: recreated means...how can i do this...need your suggestion

Comment: It seems that your lists gets filled again if you switch pages. So you have to make sure that your list is empty before it is filled again. You could add a line `stuList = new ArrayList()` in your action method before returning "stuList". Then you have an empty list. But this is only a dirty workaround and not a real solution. Please post the part of your code where the list gets filled.

Comment: kindly find the updated code..here is my list filled with database data